# Translate java object to soap

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have this (not so cool) web service:

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService()
public class WMCWeb {
}
```

And would like to do something like

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getMyObject")
public MyObject getMyObject(@WebParam(name = "id") String id) {
        ...
        return new myObject;
}
```

But I can't just return an object. I don't really know what I should do to be able to do so. I read something about writing a org.apache.soap.util.Serializer, but it seems like an old solution. How can I make the WebService know how to translate the object to a Soap response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAX-WS utilizes JAXB (the actual version of JAXB used depends on the version of JAX-WS) to perform binding between the XML document (the SOAP message on the wire) and the Java types. If you substitute the String parameter with one of type `java.lang.Object`, then the JAXB runtime is bound to find difficulties during serialization and de-serialization, as no such bindings exist that determine how the runtime should perform such a process.

I suspect that you are attempting to perform type substitution at runtime, using a super class. If that is the case, you should be using JAX-WS 2.1 and the [XmlSeeAlso](http://jax-ws.java.net/jax-ws-21-ea1/docs/annotations.html#4.5_javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso__) annotation in JAXB 2.1 to this effect; it is also recommended to construct a suitable superclass, even if you do manage to generate an appropriate WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

look at CXF or axis2. They actually do expose methods as web service and you can easily call these methods by using something like a skeleton (just like how EJB works). also, if you have the web service already(meaning the WSDL is published), you can do a WSDLtojava and it will create those objects for you.